# solr date start end gap query in solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a list of documents. Every document has a timestamp, a message code and value.

I try to calculate how many message code has occured in every second. How shall I written in solrj. ts_dt is timestamp column.

```
query.setQuery("*");
query.setFacet(true);
query.addFacetField("msgCode_s");
query.add("facet.date","ts_dt");
query.add("facet.date.start,"2015-01-23T11:35:34.653Z");
query.add("facet.date.end","2015-01-23T11:36:39.096Z");
query.add("facet.date.gap","+1SECOND");
```

[edited later] the codes does not work. It just give whole occurrence of different key codes.  I try to get every second, different key codes occurrence times.

The message code only has two values, timeout and keySend. The timestamp is from 2015-1-23T00:00:00.000Z to NOW. I want to print out every second, timeout and keySend occurrence.

Comment: so, is it working? what you asking for?

Comment: the codes does not work. It just give whole occurrence of different key codes. I try to get every second, different key codes occurrence times.